# VS 2017 Local Function Debugging Weirdness

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm seeing something weird in the debugger on VS 2017 when debugging a local function.

Please look at the code below and put a breakpoint on the `if` statement that contains a call to `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`.

When the debugger hits the line indicated, press F10. For some reason control goes to the next line: `return false;`, yet the method does not really return `false` (nor should it). Pressing F10 again causes control to drop down 
to the call, `return LocalContainsG()`.

Why does control go to the `return false;` statement when pressing F10 after hitting the breakpoint? This makes no sense to me.

```
internal class Program {
   private static void Main() {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Contains as G? " + new Program().ContainsG("pizza"));
  }

    bool ContainsG(string text) {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) // PUT BREAKPOINT HERE THEN PRESS F10
          return false; // Debugger stops here!!!

       bool LocalContainsG(string target) {
          return target.Contains("G");
       }

       return LocalContainsG(text);
    } 
}
```

Comment: One step forward, two steps back.  It is caused by the local method definition, the C# compiler emits an extra NOP opcode that should not be there.  Enough to confuse the debugger.  You need to click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) to let them know about it.  Work around it by either expecting confusion when you use local methods or by delaying the enjoyment of the new-car smell.